# Remove coupon VAT in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to remove the VAT that is added to the coupon amount in the cart when applying the coupon. For this, I use the `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` action hook like this:

```
function remove_coupon_tax($cart) {
    $coupons = $cart->get_coupon_discount_totals();

    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') || !$coupons) {
        return;
    }

    // The $cart->get_coupon_discount_tax_totals() returns an array with 
    // coupon codes as keys and the corresponding tax amount as value, 
    // which I map to set all values (tax amount) to 0 for each coupon that is added.
    $discount_tax_totals_zero = array_map(function() { 
        return 0; 
    }, $cart->get_coupon_discount_tax_totals());

    // Here I set the new array as discount_tax_totals
    $cart->set_coupon_discount_tax_totals($discount_tax_totals_zero);
    
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'remove_coupon_tax', 1, 10);
```

If I do a `var_dump($cart);` after `$cart->set_coupon_discount_tax_totals($discount_tax_totals_zero);` I see that the value of `$discount_tax_totals_zero` has been set successfully, however, the VAT is still added to the coupon amount on the cart and checkout pages. What am I missing?

Comment: Read this - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/How-Taxes-Work-in-WooCommerce

Comment: @MartinMirchev which part?